# How to clear the hash map<string,string> values?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, hashmap, adt

I want to clear all the hash map values before the values are assigned to hash map from db.For eg.,`hashmap<string,string> demo` is my hashmap in that i have added the following values from db.The result response from hashmap is `{A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4, E=5}`.After view loads I want to insert this in above hashmap `{A=test, B=demo, C=sample, D=empty, E=null}`.For this how can I clear the first values before inserting the second set of values.And also I have tried by using `demo.clear()` it is not working.How can I clear the 1st list of values before adding the 2nd one.Suggest some solutions to solve the problem.

This is the code to retrieve data from db.

```
public HashMap<String, String> getdata() {
    try {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Log.e("getdata", "Started");
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                map.put(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("colmn1")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("colmn2")));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return map;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("getdata", "Ended");
    }
    return null;

}
```

In this demo only the response coming as I explained above.And then am doing this

```
if(demo.isEmpty())
        {
//code for correct condition
        }
else
    {
     demo.clear();
    }
```

And passing the values to hash map by this way.

```
demo = dbhelper.getdata();
```

And My Logcat exceptions:

```
09-06 12:48:53.656: W/dalvikvm(5071): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fb0258)
09-06 12:48:53.660: W/System.err(5071): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{packagename/packagename.listdata}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-06 12:48:53.660: W/System.err(5071):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
09-06 12:48:53.660: W/System.err(5071):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
09-06 12:48:53.660: W/System.err(5071):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
09-06 12:48:53.660: W/System.err(5071):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
09-06 12:48:53.660: W/System.err(5071):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-06 12:48:53.660: W/System.err(5071):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
09-06 12:48:53.660: W/System.err(5071):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
09-06 12:48:53.661: W/System.err(5071):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 12:48:53.661: W/System.err(5071):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-06 12:48:53.661: W/System.err(5071):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
09-06 12:48:53.661: W/System.err(5071):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
09-06 12:48:53.661: W/System.err(5071):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-06 12:48:53.661: W/System.err(5071): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-06 12:48:53.661: W/System.err(5071):     at packagename.listdata.onCreate(listdata.java:231)
09-06 12:48:53.661: W/System.err(5071):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479)
09-06 12:48:53.661: W/System.err(5071):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
09-06 12:48:53.661: W/System.err(5071):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
```

Comment: "I have tried `demo.clear()` it is not working" - what do you mean "it is not working"? Show your code, otherwise it will be very hard to explain why it doesn't work in your program.

Comment: demo.clear() should work the way it is supposed to

Comment: @Jesper "it is not working" means it is throwing null pointer exception at the place where I have used "demo.clear()".So only I have mentioned that

Comment: Please show code. `clear()` does work.

Comment: @SabariKarthik Then something else is wrong in your program but without seeing the code it's impossible to say what's wrong.

Comment: If it crashes, show code plus logcat.

Comment: The exception is thrown in listdata.java:231. Can you show this code?

Comment: What's line listdata.java:231? and how have you initialized the `demo`?

Comment: listdata.java:231 points to this only " demo.clear();".And am not able to list the whole code due to confidential matter.

Comment: That's fine. We all understand that. How have you initialized demo?

Comment: *"And am not able to list the whole code due to confidential matter."* - It is time to close the Question then.  If you can't / won't show us enough of the code, we can't help you.  The best we can say is that your "theory" that `clear()` does not work is INCORRECT.

Comment: have you tried using `if(demo == null || demo.isEmpty())`?

Comment: After this "public class listdata extends Activity {" I have declared Hash map as HashMap<String, String> demo;  @Dhruti

Comment: also tried this `if(demo == null || demo.isEmpty())` the app crashes  @shyam

Comment: Demo must be null. Try if demo!= null and then call isempty on it 8n if condition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`hMap.clear()` always worked fine for me.

Still

```
hMap.put("A","test");
```

will automatically override the existing value for key "A".

If you still wish to clear values,

You can use

```
hMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

which will initialize a new hashmap in `hMap`.

Comment: But why claer is not working ?? That is actually the OP's question.

Comment: It always worked for me. You might be doing some mistake. Please show code.

Comment: You must ask the same question to OP :)

Comment: @SabariKarthik Have you read the whole post. `hMap = new HashMap<String,String>();` is the solution provided.

Comment: @SabariKarthik please show code. if `demo.clear()` gives NPE, that means you are calling it at a wrong place (before initialization). Please check. and show code.

Comment: any luck? @SabariKarthik